# Common jQuery function for conditional undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose, I'm doing something like below in the same javascript file (eg. `app.js`):

```
// triggers in both add and edit mode
var purchase = $('.purchase-selector').doSomething();
// triggers only on edit mode where, purchase_data is available
if( typeof purchase_data !== 'undefined' ) {
    purchase.anotherThing(purchase_data);
}

// triggers in both add and edit mode
var sales = $('.sales-selector').doSomething();
// triggers only on edit mode where, sales_data is available
if( typeof sales_data !== 'undefined' ) {
    sales.anotherThing(sales_data);
}
```

The issue is, without the Purchase Edit mode there's no `purchase_data` variable is available. Same is true for the `sales_data` where it's only available on the Sales Edit mode.

The code is working fine, but actually, I'm doing it against the DRY principle (my code is a way too lengthy). So I tried making a simple method to remove the DRY.

```
var the_thing = function(selector, edit_data) {
    var thing = selector.doSomething();
    if( typeof edit_data !== 'undefined' ) {
        thing.anotherThing(edit_data);
    }
};

the_thing($('.purchase-selector'), purchase_data);
the_thing($('.sales-selector'), sales_data);
```

But the issue is it's generating `Uncaught ReferenceError: purchase_data is not defined` (same for the `sales_data` too).

So I tried something like below:

```
if( typeof purchase_data === 'undefined' ) {
   var purchase_data;
}
the_thing($('.purchase-selector'), purchase_data);

if( typeof sales_data === 'undefined' ) {
   var sales_data;
}
the_thing($('.sales-selector'), sales_data);
```

But it's making the `purchase_data` (object) to `undefined` as well.

In edit mode:

```
console.log(typeof purchase_data);
```

is returning:

```
object
```

but with the following code:

```
console.log(typeof purchase_data);
if( typeof purchase_data === 'undefined' ) {
   var purchase_data;
}
console.log(typeof purchase_data);
```

It's showing:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Can't I use a concept of function in *this* case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because your `purchase_data` and `sales_data` variables need to be defined before they can be used (even when checking to see if they were assigned a value).

What you can do is, create a function to check if a variable has been assigned a value:

```
function isUndefined(valor) {
    return (typeof valor === 'undefined');
}
```

Then, among your other code, you need to define said variabled before they are used in any function:

```
var purchase_data;
var sales_data;
```

Then you can make reference to the variables in which if no values have been assigned, they will be of type `undefined` which you can check using the above function:

```
var the_thing = function(selector, edit_data) {
    var thing = selector.doSomething();

    if(!isUndefined(edit_data)) {
        thing.anotherThing(edit_data);
    }
};

the_thing($('.purchase-selector'), purchase_data);
the_thing($('.sales-selector'), sales_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `purchase_data` has to be defined for using it as an argument for the function. Because it is not defined, it cannot be evaluated before the actual call of the function. This causes the error.

When you say var `purchase_data;`, the variable is known, so it can be used as an  argument. But it still has no value, so typeof is `undefined`.